# how to display data from database in table view in python

Tags: python, pyside

I am new to python and been stuck with an issue, any one please help me to solve this issue. Requirement is I have created a sqlite database and created a table and also inserted values to it but the problem is I am not getting how to display that data from database in table view in python so please help me out from this.....advance thanks..

```
db_con = sqlite3.Connection
db_name = "./patientData.db"
createDb = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
queryCurs = createDb.cursor()
queryCurs.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PATIENT
    (NAME TEXT NOT NULL, ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, AGE INTEGER NOT NULL, GENDER TEXT NOT NULL , EYE_TYPE TEXT NOT NULL)''')

pName = self.patientEdit.text()
pId =self.patientidEdit.text()
#pId1 = int(pId)
pAge = self.ageEdit.text()
#pAge1 = int(pAge)
pGender = self.patientgend.text()
pEye_type = self.eyeTypeEdit.text()
queryCurs.execute('''INSERT INTO PATIENT(NAME,ID,AGE, GENDER,EYE_TYPE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''',(pName, pId, pAge, pGender, pEye_type))
print ('Inserted row')
createDb.commit()
```

now how can I dispaly data in a tableview /listview any example code is also helpful

Comment: What did you try until now?

Comment: i was trying with QlistWidget like:

Comment: patientList = QtGui.QListWidget() qitem = Qtgui.QListWidgetItem(queryCurs)

Comment: why do you use a QListWidget to display a table instead of a QTableView???

Comment: no i just tried with Qlistview as i was not having idea to how to display through table view. so if have any example code on QtableView please send to me it will a be great help to a beginner like me.....

Comment: I wrote a complete and very simple example. Please check it, it should be straightforward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a short, albeit complete example on how to achieve the expected result.
The trick is to define a [QSqlQueryModel](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtSql/QSqlQueryModel.html?highlight=qsqlquerymodel#PySide.QtSql.QSqlQueryModel) and pass it to a [QTableView](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTableView.html); in this way you use the PyQt4 SQL modules instead of `sqlite3` module, and the table can loop the query result automatically.

```
from PyQt4.QtSql import QSqlQueryModel,QSqlDatabase,QSqlQuery
from PyQt4.QtGui import QTableView,QApplication
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName("patientData.db")
db.open()

projectModel = QSqlQueryModel()
projectModel.setQuery("select * from patient",db)

projectView = QTableView()
projectView.setModel(projectModel)

projectView.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has been a long time ago and the accepted one is for PyQt4. Because the API has been changed a bit on PyQt5, hope my answer can help someone using PyQt5.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtSql
# connect to postgresql
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
db.setHostName(**)
db.setDatabaseName(**)
db.setPort(**) # int
db.setUserName(**)
db.setPassword(**)

# create tableview
tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView()

# create sqlquery
query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
result = query.exec_("""select * from "table" """)
if result:
    model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(db=db)
    model.setQuery(query)
    tableView.setModel(model)
    tableView.show()
```